# Python IF OR -> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a column "PreHeat" and i would like to create a new column "PreHeat_Outlier_TestX", where will be written, if the value is an outlier or not (True, False).

I can manage it with one condition:

```
df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = (df['PreHeat'] > df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.75))
```

But when i tried to use OR or if, ifelse i have got the following error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
if (df['PreHeat'] > df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.75)):
    df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = True
elif (df['PreHeat'] < df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.25)):
    df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = True
else: 
    df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = False


if (df['PreHeat'] > df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.75)) or (df['PreHeat'] < df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.25)):
   df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = True
else:
   df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = False
```

I am not sure, what is wrong with the code.
Could somebody help me?

Comment: following `if` should always be a single boolean `True` or `False`. You passed a series, which cannot be cast to a boolean. checkout `np.select`.

Answer (score 0):

following if should always be a single boolean `True` or `False`. You passed a series, which cannot be cast to a boolean. checkout `np.select`

Similarly with `or`, also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

What you are trying to do with

```
if (df['PreHeat'] > df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.75)):
    df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = True
elif (df['PreHeat'] < df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.25)):
    df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = True
else: 
    df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = False
```

should be done with

```
df['PreHeat_Outlier_TestX'] = ~df['PreHeat'].between(df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.25), df['PreHeat'].quantile(0.75))
```